# Add custom attribute on Joomla menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

im triying to add an attribute to a item on Joomla menu but fail.

Im designin a site that is like "one page" with Warp Framework and the uikit has a smooth scroll option. Im just have to add "data-uk-smooth-scroll" on the link as a attribute

My menu has some items that links to anchors but i want them to feel smooth.

In other forums i read that i can do it using Jquery to add to all href that start with #, the code i use and fail in this

```
    $('a[href*=#]').prop('data-uk-smooth-scroll');
```

Is this the way or is a way to do it inside the joomla menu options.

Greetings (and sorry for my terrific english)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that using jquery is the best approach. You could locate where menu is generated (template file or module) and add the property there. If you want to continue with jQuery solution you have to check the following issues.

The [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method with single parameter gets the value of a property, doesn't set it. You have to use the folowing syntax: `.prop( propertyName, value )`.

Another issue is that joomla loads [jQuery in noConflict mode](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Javascript_Frameworks) so `$` calls has to be changed with `jQuery` like:

```
jQuery('a[href*=#]').prop('data-uk-smooth-scroll', value);
```

As for the selector you have chosen, it's too generic and will target all anchors in the document. It's better to add the menu `id` or `class` to restrict it's scope like: `jQuery('#menu_id a[href*=#]')`.

Hope this helps.